# Best way to store collection of objects in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I am creating a dump Java app for student information system for learning and implementing OOPS Concepts like inheritance, abstraction, polymorphism and encapsulation.

What I am doing is, I have created `Faculty` Class, `Student` Class and a College Class. Now i want to add new faculty in College. So my approach is to create a method in College class i.e. `addFaculty(Faculty f)` and `fireFaculty(Faculty f)`, now i want to add `Faculties` in `College` class.

Whats the best way to do it? How do i store list of `Faculty` Object in `College` Object. Because i can add more than one faculty and more than one student in college.

Whats the best approach to solve this problem in OOPS?

Here is College.java code which i have implemented, it works fine but is this the best way i can solve it?

```
public class College 
{
String name;
String location;
String courses[];
HashMap<String,Faculty> faculties;
int noOfFaculties = 0;
int noOfStudents = 0;

public College(String name,String location,String courses[])
{
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.courses = courses;
    faculties = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addFaculty(Faculty faculty)
{
    faculties.put(faculty.getName(),faculty);
}

public void printFaculties()
{
    Set<String> set = faculties.keySet();
    if(set.size()>0)
    {
        for(String s:set)
        {
            System.out.println(faculties.get(s).getName());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Faculties Currently Working");
    }
}

public void fireFaculty(Faculty faculty)
{
    faculties.remove(faculty.getName());
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getLocation()
{
    return location;
}

public String[] getCourses()
{
    return courses;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code for the classes that you have? To add multiple faculty in the college object, just add some kind of collection field in the College.

Comment: Just create a list of faculties or something as a property in college to keep track of them.

Comment: OOPS! Draw UML class diagram.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a ton of ways you can do it. Probably the easiest way to handle storing a collection of objects is by using one of the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) provided by Java. For beginners, probably the easiest one to understand is an `ArrayList`, which is basically an array that grows in size dynamically depending on the amount of objects in the collection.

So, as an axample, your code might be something like this:

```
public class College
{
    private ArrayList<Faculty> faculty;

    public College()
    {
        faculty = new ArrayList<Faculty>();
    }

    public void addFaculty(Faculty f)
    {
        faculty.add(f);
    }

    public void fireFaculty(Faculty f)
    {
        faculty.remove(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot have duplicates use `HashSet<Faculty>` if you dont mind use a `List<Faculty>`.

Example:

```
class College {
    private List<Faculty> listFactories = new ArrayList<>();  // dupes allowed
    private Set<Faculty> setFactories = new HashSet<>(); // no dupes allowed
}
```

[Check collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Answer (score 0):

imho It depends what kind of services College college offers. If I were coding, I would start with:-

```
List<Faculy> faculties = new ArrayList<>();
....
public void addFaculty(Faculty f) {
  faculties.add(f);
 }
 //... etc
```

And change to an altearnative later if needed.